# How to track online users with Facebook login?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am using timestamp to fetch online users with php

```
$time=time()-5;
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE timestamp>$time ");
```

How can i do this if the user logged in with facebook login plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[online_presence The user's Facebook Chat status](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/).

Returns a string, one of `active, idle, offline, or error` (when Facebook can't determine presence information on the server side). The query does not return the `user's Facebook Chat` status when that information is restricted for privacy reasons

TO GET IN `PHP` through Query.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE online_presence
IN ('active', 'idle') AND timestamp>$time ");
```

Comment: i need to check it with php